# Why would a dissolved geometry take 100x longer to run an SJOIN than if the geometry wasn't dissolved?

Tags: geopandas

There is quite a lot of detail in my code, so if it's necessary I will post it below, but I'd like to avoid specifics if possible.

As of right now, I have 10 different datasets/geodataframes. For 8 of them, when I dissolve their geometries and run an SJOIN, this is **faster** than if I just ran the SJOIN without the dissolve.

For the 9th dataset, running an SJOIN without dissolving it would take a **VERY** long time, and so the dissolve is necessary.

However, for the 10th dataset, running the SJOIN without a dissolve takes **seconds**, but if I dissolve first then run an SJOIN, it will be the only dataset where it takes longer to run the SJOIN (and it takes at least 100x longer).

Shouldn't the SJOIN be faster with a dissolve? Why would the SJOIN take 100x less time when I don't dissolve for the 10th dataset?

Comment: Join performance is linked to vertex count.

Comment: If this were the case, wouldn't the SJOIN of the dissolved geodataframe be much faster, since there are less vertices? This isn't the case for all of my dataframes though, as the 10th dataframe runs 100x slower when dissolved (even though it has less vertices).

Comment: It's not linked to *just* vertex count. But you would have to provide the exact data to do an analysis on why that particular feature was different.

Comment: There is too much room for guessing without test data and re-producible test case.

Comment: While for a different technology, this [article](https://carto.com/blog/subdivide-all-things/) shows that using small polygons will 1) improve the index-based bounding box intersection selection and 2) simplify the exact point in polygon intersection computation (less vertices to work with), leading to a 60x improvement.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!