# Does it make sense that dissolving geometries would make an R-Tree intersection query run much slower?

Tags: geopandas

I have a dataset that runs 100x faster on an SJOIN intersection spatial query when the geometries are NOT dissolved. There are about 12,000 individual polygons, but when I dissolve them based on one of the columns in my geodataframe, I only have a total of about 1,000 multipolygons.

Now, because the multipolygons pretty much span the entire length of the map, I'm assuming the SJOIN intersection query runs 100x slower due to how the R-Tree is searched through in the algorithm.  Is this the correct way to think about the R-Tree and why my intersection algorithm takes 100x slower when running a dissolve function?

Comment: Is this the same question that you asked in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445153/why-would-a-dissolved-geometry-take-100x-longer-to-run-an-sjoin-than-if-the-geom?

Comment: Different question, but same answer: bigger geometries take longer to process.